# Смещение аннотаций по оси х в matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Есть [датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zh6cPoWkIsAnmXnySEPM-K5O48vzcqph/view?usp=sharing), по нему строится график. На графике отмечаются аннотации в виде максимальных значений. Я пытаюсь выставить аннотации по центру столбцов, путем их смещения. Смещение по оси `y` так, чтобы аннотация не касалась самих столбцов, получается. Смещение вправо почему-то не работает. Код:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

phones = pd.read_csv('1.8_phones.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=None)
phones.drop(phones.index[0],  inplace=True)
phones.rename(columns={0: 'disk', 1: 'os', 2: 'price', 3: 'year'}, inplace=True)
phones['disk'] = phones['disk'].astype(int)
phones['price'] = phones['price'].astype(int)
phones['year'] = phones['year'].astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 6))
ax.hist(phones['price'], bins = 20, color = 'green')
plt.xlabel('Цена')
plt.ylabel('Кол-во моделей')
plt.title('Распределение цен телефонов', fontsize = 15)
ax.grid()
for i in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate('%1.0f'%(i.get_height()),(i.get_x()+1, i.get_height()+0.2), fontsize = 8)
plt.show()
```

Почему не работает смещение аннотаций в

> i.get_x()+1

Вместо 1 может быть любое число.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уверены, что не работает? у вас величина смещения довольно маленькая, чтобы было заметно, кроме того, `get_x` возвращает координату левого края столбца, а не его середины

Comment: проверил. все работает со смещением. у вас по оси `x` - отмечаются тысячи. а вы прибавляете смещение в адиницу.

Comment: @strawdog А, то есть не в точках, а в единицах самого `x` считается видимо, теперь понятно, а я то думаю почему такая разница в масштабах. Логично.

Comment: @strawdog Для смещения по оси у хватило 0,1, с иксом рассуждал теми же порядками смещений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
for i in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate('%1.0f'%(i.get_height()),(i.get_x()+i.get_width()/2, i.get_height()+0.2), fontsize = 8)
```

получите это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Почему-то высота и ширина похоже в разных единицах считаются, для `x` 1 это очень мало. У меня нормально отцентрировалось примерно по такой формуле:

```
i.get_x()+i.get_width()//2-10
```